What is the optimal way to manage the creation of objects of the same type that only differ in the values of their fields?
I have encountered this scenario several times but I couldn't find a definitive answer on the optimal way to manage it.
Here's the issue. I have a Java 21 backend application that provides a React app with data. The frontend should display several different kinds of notification messages. These messages are built server side.
In the real scenario, I have a lot of different types of notification messages possible. However, to simplify, let us suppose there are only 3:

Generic Notification
Alert Notification
Offer Notification

The Notification messages all have the same structure, they have a title and a body. Every notification type is dynamically computed based on the current user and the current page and needs a separate logic to be built.
I though about modeling Notifications using records:
record Notification(String title, String body) {}

And then, I used a simple factory pattern to manage their creation
enum NotificationType {
    GENERIC, ALERT, OFFER
}


final class NotificationFactory {
    
    Notification create(Context context, NotificationType type) {
        return switch(type) {
            case GENERIC -> createGenericMessage(context);
            case ALERT -> createAlertMessage(context);
            case OFFER -> createOfferMessage(context);
        }
    }
    
    // implementations of private methods
}

However, I am not 100% convinced this is the best approach and I usually see the Factory pattern associated with different subclasses of the same type. Instead, in this case the only difference between a notification type and another is the value of their fields and the way those values are retrieved.
What am I missing? Thank you in advance
UPDATE: Corrected some errors in NotificationFactory (e.g., I used Message instead of Notification).

You use words like "best" and "optimal", but that just seems like a matter of opinion here. Your solution works, and it was the most intuitive one to you, because you came up with it.

You didn’t show the Message class, so it’s unclear what is actually needed. It could be as simple as record Message(NotificationType type, Notification text) {}, then, there is no need for having three different factory methods. The NotificationType seems to be given already (as otherwise, you couldn’t think about using a switch), so you can pass it to the message constructor and you’re done.

Sorry @Holger, I meant to use Notification instead of Message as a return type. Before posting the question I used different names and I forgot to change it.

Your approach seems pretty good.  Sure, there are other ways one could do it, but I don’t think they would be any better.

Personally in this example I would go with enum abstract method "create".
You are removing switch with that so when adding new notification element someone immedietly sees that they need to implement create method and there is no need to change that switch.
Basically you create abstract method inside your enum then every enum value needs to implement that method so you have something like that:
    enum NotificationType {
        GENERIC_NOTIFICATION {
            @Override
            public Notification create(Object context) {
                return null;
            }
        },
        ALERT_NOTIFICATION {
            @Override
            public Notification create(Object context) {
                return null;
            }
        },
        OFFER_NOTIFICATION {
            @Override
            public Notification create(Object context) {
                return null;
            }
        };
        
        public abstract Notification create(Object context);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testSth() {
        NotificationType type = NotificationType.ALERT_NOTIFICATION; // I assumed that you know the type beforehand
        Object context = null; // your context, probably different type than Object
        
        type.create(context);
    }

From your implemented methods you should call some static factory or something depending on what you need.
You can also create more methods, depends on use case.
The only downside with this approach is that you need to pass through everything needed or call database methods to retrieve informations.
So depends on how your app structure looks like it could be good or not.
If you have some global session objects which are managed by your framework and you can access them everywhere on session scope level and you need a lot of them it would be probably tideus to pass it through every time.
But putting that aside I personally like this approach for one reason. If I have a lot of types and a lot of places where I use all of them then while adding new one I just need to implement few methods that have different implementation for each one and I don't need to check for every references of enums where are switch cases to add new one everywhere.
Also I'm not sure that there is definitive good for all cases answer to your question :)

"and I don't need to check for every references of enums where are switch cases to add new one everywhere."
Java has exhaustiveness checking for switch cases now, so it's not a matter of having to check. The compiler will tell you if you forgot one.

I'm not exactly sure which compiler will say that you have 13 switch cases where you didn't use one enum value but mine sure does not

Switch expressions, which is what OP is using (return switch). Java 14+. https://openjdk.org/jeps/361#Exhaustiveness

It only shows error if you return switch statement and only if before adding new value to your enum you already had every enum value in that switch statement, if you had only like half of them and "default" section then you also will not see an error

"return switch statement" There is no such thing as returning a statement. This is a switch expression. It works anywhere you use a switch expression, which is not limited to returning a value; it works for assignment too. "if you had only like half of them and "default" section" which OP does not.

OP asked general question which was stated in his first sentence, and his code is only one example of several times encountering this issue. So in my opinion saying that he does have or doesn't in his code is just you trying to defend your argument. "return switch statement" - my bad I meant switch statement yielding value. And I still believe that compiler won't tell you every place where switch was used unless you will only use yield switch statements without default sections in your code.

"my bad I meant switch statement yielding value." You meant switch expression, which I already said, but anyway. You used exhaustiveness as one way in which your impl is an improvement over theirs. The only point I made is that exhaustiveness is already accounted for.

Providing a default in a switch expression is like providing a non-abstract create method as fallback in the enum type. Both is possible and neither says anything about the approach in general. You can use either construct in a way that the compiler will tell you when a new constant is not handled. Letting aside that you don’t always have the option to change the enum type, in the OP’s case, constructing an object consisting of two message strings does not sound like a task deserving different factory methods. The message construction logic likely has a lot in common for all cases.
